# How do you say 'grook' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

No translation is given in Benson, nor Wells, nor Vikivortaro.
Here is the link to the Wikipedia article on this item:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grook

Comment: A collection of Piet Hein's *Grooks* has been translated to Esperanto as *Gruk*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely an established Esperanto word for this already exists. I'm unsure what exactly characterizes a "grook" and thus whether it can captured by a kunmetaĵo that is both sufficiently concise (i.e., short) and also sufficiently precise (to avoid confusion with non-grook types of similar sorts of poems or aphorisms).

If "grook" just means "aphoristic poem or rhyming aphorism" and if further each and every aphoristic poem or rhyming aphorism can be considered a grook, then a kunmetaĵo would probably do. Obvious suggestions in that case would be

- aforisma poemo
- poema aforismo
- poemaforismo
- aforisma rimo
- rimata aforismo
- rimataforismo
- rimaforismo

If not every aphoristic poem or rhyming aphorism is a grook and there is no concise way to circumscribe a grook in existing Esperanto words, we should introduce a new root for it. In that case, based on the pronunciation of the English "grook" and on the spelling of the danish "gruk", I'd suggest the new root

> gruk-

Thus a grook (as a noun) would be

> gruko